# firebase.getDatabase()).ref() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

Hello I'm doing a project shcool on `nodeJS` and work with firebase.
I try to get the `name` of a `users` to not rewrite an existing value.
the db is:

[image: the db]

my code to try something:

serv.js

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHDOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASEURL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECTID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGEBUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSASGINGSENDERID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APPID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENTID
};

const {initializeApp} = require('firebase/app');
const {getDatabase} = require('firebase/database');
const {getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword, createUserWithEmailAndPassword} = require('firebase/auth');

const fireapp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getDatabase(fireapp);
var firebaseauth = getAuth(fireapp);
[...]

function create_entry_name(name, email)
{
  const ref = db.ref('/users/' + name);

  ref.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  }, (errorObject) => {
    console.log('The read failed: ' + errorObject.name);
  });
}
```

that's litteraly the example on the firebase website.

But I get an error witch is:

```
db.ref is not a function
```

I will really be thanks full if you have an solution for this problem...

Comment: Do you know for sure if you're initializing/stating `db` properly? Try console logging it and see if it is what you expect.

Comment: To be honest I don't really know what I expect to get from ```db```, I consoled log him but that doesn't give me a clue... @insyri

Comment: ooof there is so much wrong here. Follow the docs here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start

Comment: Hello, so I updated my code with the firebase tuto and your help but I get the exact same error... @BrianMcCall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Modular SDK (`v9.0.0+`) but using syntax of older name-spaced syntax. Try refactoring the code as follows:

```
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue} from "firebase/database";

function create_entry_name(name, email) {
  const ref = ref(db, '/users/' + name);

  onValue(ref, (snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.val();
    console.log(data)
  });
}
```

You can find more details about the new syntax in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web_value_events).

Comment: It's so frustrating.  I see NONE of that new syntax in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Call the getDatabase directly. It's already initialized.

```
const db = getDatabase();
const ref = db.ref('/users/'+ name);
```

Comment: Code Updated and same error

Answer (score 0):

Build the app from the app library...

```
import { firebaseApp } from 'firebase/app';
const app = initializeApp({/*config*/});
```

Then get the database *from the initialized app*. Note that the OP fails to pass a param to `getDatabase`...

```
const db = getDatabase(app);

const ref = db.ref('users/' + name);
// etc...
```

Comment: Hello, so I updated my code with the firebase tuto and your help but I get the exact same error...@danh